# How to get params from checkbox in rails3 controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

Here is my codes:

```
<%=form_tag('/user_group_follows/follow',:id=>'follow_select_form',:remote=>true,:method=>:get) do %>
    <p>You want to add this user to?</p>
    <%=hidden_field_tag 'user_id',@user.id%>
    <%@user.user_groups.each do |ug|%>
        <%=check_box_tag 'user_group_id',ug.id,false,{:id=>'user_group_id_'+ug.id.to_s}%><%=ug.name%><br/>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
//using jquery-ui, so there is no submit button....
```

I wanna the user to make a multiple choice to decide which groups that he/she would like to add into the following list.

So I made several checkboxes with the same name as 'user_group_id' and different ids. 
I could successfully get the params throught params[:user_group_id], **if the user only checked one box.** But if he truly checked several of them, how to get this value set in controller? In this circumstance, params[:user_group_id] could only get one of them. And I quite believe codes like: params[:user_group_id_+XXX.id] is not going to work....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you name them with id's like `user_group_id['+ug.id+']`, I think you should get params like `params[:user_group_id]` which should contain an array of all the id's of groups that were checked.

Something like this, not sure exactly, but basically you want to name your fields such that they are grouped into an array naturally, by virtue of how they are named:

```
<%=check_box_tag 'user_group_id['+ug.id']',ug.id,false,{:id=>'user_group_id_'+ug.id.to_s}%><%=ug.name%>
```

So, `params[:user_group_id].first` would contain the id of the first checkbox that was selected.

Comment: em...I think it is not working, params[:user_group_id].first only returns 1, but actually the expected user_group_id should be 28 and 29...

Comment: Well, I have got it, the codes should be: <%=check_box_tag 'user_group_id[]'%> so that the Rails will recognize params[:user_group_id]as an array! Thanks anyway, your answer really did a great hint!

Answer (score 0):

if you go in this way <%=check_box_tag 'user_group_id[]'%> it's returning array of selected ids,

```
<%=check_box_tag 'user_group_id',ug.id, params[:user_group_id].try(:include?,ug.id.to_s),{:id=>'user_group_id_'+ug.id.to_s}%>
```